# C++14 and C++17 in one project

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, c++14, c++17

I have a project, which builds in VS2017 with C++17 standard. I recently added some dependencies to that project. Now, I get errors like this one: `...\include\xmltooling\util\parserpool.h(193): error C2039: 'auto_ptr': is not a member of 'std'`.

Now, as far as a I can see, there are two possibilities:

1. Change the code of that external library.
2. Build parts of the projects with C++17 and other parts with older C++ standard, like C++14. Or in other words: Build one C++-file in C++14 and all other in C++17.

Now, some questions occurred (sorry, if some questions seems to be dumb).

Is point 2. doable? The VS solution is generated with `CMake`. When point 2. is doable, how this can be done with `CMake`.

If point 2. is not doable, are there other ways except point 1. solving this problem?

Comment: I never tried this, but maybe you could build two libraries, each with a different c++ standard setting via `target_compile_features(${LIBRARY_NAME_A} PRIVATE cxx_std_14)` and `target_compile_features(${LIBRARY_NAME_B} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)`

Answer (score 5):

You just need to define `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC` to `1`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/08/c17-feature-removals-and-deprecations/

However if `std::auto_ptr` was being used correctly `std::unique_ptr` should be a drop in replacement in most cases. You should just be able to do a search and replace from `auto_ptr` to `unique_ptr`.